# B2C - Terms of Service and Social Sign In - How to prevent AzureB2C from always asking to check the Terms of Service everytime a user signs in via IDP

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

I am trying to implement a custom policy that allows a user to sign in/sign up locally or via via FB, Google, etc.  I used the sample policy from this link:  https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-sign-up-versioned-tou

My problem is everytime the user signs in via IDP, they always get prompted to agree to the terms of service.

How do I prevent this?  I would like the users to agree once and not be prompted on subsequent IDP sign ins.

Comment: That project has no social support. So I assume you added it? Are you using "AlternativeSecurityId" instead of "ObjectId" to read/write the social attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a new sample which integrates the logic for social accounts also. The following changes needed to be applied:

1. Generate current time at start of journey, and not after submitting local account credentials.
2. Read the extension attribute on the social account
3. Compare the time on the extension with the claim transform during the user journey for only social accounts
4. On Social account sign up, add TOU checkbox, and write current time to TOU extension attribute when writing the account

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-sign-up-versioned-tou-with-social